# How to change my windows ubuntu subsystem to the original colors of gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome

How to change my windows ubuntu subsystem colors to the original like in gnome-terminnal ?

Comment: What terminal software are you using to access WSL? Are you using the standard Windows console, or the Windows Terminal app, or something else?

Comment: i simply open it , it's cmd i think

Answer (score 0):

How to configure gnome-terminal appearance and features is described in [gnome-terminal's documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/).